# I cannot add a certain tag to my question

Tags: support, tags

I might be unaware of a certain functionality here but when I am trying to add the tag named `odoo` to one of my questions it is replaced by `openerp`. Since the product has been renamed from `openerp` to `odoo` shouldn't the new tag remain rather than being replaced by the old one?

Comment: I had a similar problem with a question that had `sql` and `sql-update` as tags. The last one was marked as a synonym for the first one and it was automatically removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo) tag is a *synonym* of [openerp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openerp), as can be seen on the [tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/odoo/synonyms). Therefore, your tag is replaced when you try to add it to a question.

<strike>If you want to suggest to reverse this mapping, you can ask for that on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) - like this question, questions which pertain only to a single site in the Stack Exchange network should be asked on the site's own Meta, not here.</strike> (no longer applicable since it has migrated now)